# How to fix this Error Unexpected null value?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the following error while rendering in my FutureBuilder:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown during paint(): Unexpected null value.
```

Here is my code:

```
file1.dart  
 DataCell(IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return VendorDetailBox(document.data()['uid']);
                });
          },
        )),
      ]);


 file.dart
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder(
            future: _services.vendors.doc(widget.uid).get(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Something Went Wrong'));
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
              return Dialog(
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .3,
                  child: ListView(children: [
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 100,
                          width: 100,
                          child: Image.network(
                            snapshot.data['url'],
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                        ListView(children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 20,
                          ),
                          Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  snapshot.data['name'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  snapshot.data['dialog'],
                                ),
                              ]),
                        ]),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      thickness: 4,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Text("Contact Numbers",
                                      style: VendorDetailTextStyle),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10),
                                  child: Text(':'),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Text(snapshot.data['mobile']),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                  child: Container(
                                child: Text("Email", style: VendorDetailTextStyle),
                              )),
                              Container(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10),
                                  child: Text(':'),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Text(snapshot.data['email']),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                  child: Container(
                                child:
                                    Text("address", style: VendorDetailTextStyle),
                              )),
                              Container(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10),
                                  child: Text(':'),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Text(snapshot.data['address']),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        // Padding(
                        //   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                        //   child: Row(
                        //     children: [
                        //       Expanded(
                        //           child: Container(
                        //         child: Text("Created At",
                        //             style: VendorDetailTextStyle),
                        //       )),
                        //       Container(
                        //         child: Padding(
                        //           padding:
                        //               const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10),
                        //           child: Text(':'),
                        //         ),
                        //       ),
                        //       Expanded(
                        //         child: Container(
                        //           child:
                        //               Text(snapshot.data['Created At'].toString()),
                        //         ),
                        //       ),
                        //     ],
                        //   ),
                        // ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: ======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown during paint():
Unexpected null value.